# Application Not Responding (ANR) executing service android

Tags: android, service, runtime-error

[image: error service]

host.activity is my package and host.framework.ServicePromemoria is an android service.

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means that your service is doing a rather long operation (most ANRs are from operations greater than 5 seconds) and is doing it on the UI thread. This could be a network task, or a database task, or some other long operation.

You can fix this by running the task in a service off the main UI thread, by using a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Infact, you can directly start your service into a new thread as follows:

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
public void run(){
getApplicationContext().bindService(
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class),
        serviceConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    );
}
};
t.start();
```

Also, cache the value returned by bindservice, if any, if you require it for later use.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm using an AsyncTask for download operation.

Comment: Post the code of the service then. And try copy pasting the logcat. It's hard to read in your image.

Comment: at this moment, I am not sure what is: serviceConnection

Comment: calling bindService() on a seperate thread  didn't actually do the work on a seperate thread.

Answer (score 4):

Although there is an accepted answer but I want do add something additional here .The reason "Application Not Responding (ANR) executing service android" is that your Service does not finished it's lifecycle call (like onCreate) during the timeout . and the default timeout for a normal service is 20s . if you need an block operate in a Servcie onCreate you need start a new Thread or you can just use the IntentService .